# Solr case insentive query and case insenstive facet

Tags: solr, lucene, facet

I have following field in schema.xml

```
<field name="Make" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>           
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

now when I am searching Make:gmc and Make:GMC I am getting result in both. But in facet I am getting lowercase results (i.e gmc). I want facet to return GMC.

```
I tried removing <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
```

It now showing facet in capitals but didn't search Make:gmc

it only return result for Make:GMC

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate copy field for your facet that doesn't use the LowerCaseFilterFactory in it's fieldType.

Comment: I created a field Make_c and copy Make field in it. Now I am fetching facet from Make_c with capital data.